# Accidentally changed workspace without checking updated items in

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have a big problem. One of my coworkers left the company yesterday and one of his projects went into my hands. We work for a company which set up a TFS for us to work together on one big project. He accessed the TFS by using his LiveID. When he left yesterday, he hasn't checked in his new/updated items and I forgot to do it today before I disconnected him and logged in with my account.

So basically I still have the updated solution on my local hard disk. But since my workspace is mapped to another folder, it actually downloaded old versions of our code files.

How can I copy the updated, not-checked-in items into my local workspace folder and check them in?

**UPDATE:** I have tried changing the local workspace folder by going to `File --> Source Control --> Workspaces` but I get another error telling me that the folder I'm trying to map (the one used by my ex-coworker) belongs to somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to log in as him, but a it is a Microsoft ID rather than an AD account you are kind of scuppered there. You o however have the files from disk. If you copy the files from his workspace and drop them over the top of your workspace TFS will detect the adds and edits for you. You will then have to go through and look for any deletes yourself..

a...make sure it builds, run all your unit tests, and then check in.

Comment: this partly worked. I talked with a colleague of mine and he told me the same thing. the only problem here was that I could not check in the latest sources as they were still marked as checked out by my ex-coworker. the tfs admin had to check them in so I could properly check them out and in again.